# Managing resources and keeping them out of version control

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone app will have a map with about `10` points on it. It will play sound files based on the proximity to those points.

What's the best way of managing these resources?

- Coordinates and accompanying sound file could be stored in a plist, as an array of dicts with latitude, longitude and file name. Then the sound files could be stored separately.
- The plist and sound files should not be version controlled.
- How much, and what, should happen compile-time, and run-time? How do I manage this?

The end result should be an app binary with the sound files embedded and the records stored in core data. Doing stuff on first launch of app is also OK.

I think my question could be rephrased to: how do I manage resources programatically, at build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the sounds folder as a 'folder reference'. Then any files you add to that folder will be included in your bundle. Right click on your project->Add Existing Files then choose 'Create Folder References'

[image: Right click on project, Add Existing Files]